# Insert multiple BSonDocuments from file into MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, import, bson

I have a text file with the following JSON info:

```
{
  "name" : "system-admin",
  "description" : "Administrador de Sistema",
  "id" : 9,
  "roleid" : 6
}{
  "name" : "rs-promo-server",
  "description" : "Servidor de Promo",
 "id" : 10,
 "roleid" : 7
```

}

I'm trying to insert multiple BSONDocuments into Mongo with the following code:

```
BsonDocument doc = BsonDocument.Parse(Json); //Json is a string variable that holds the file    content            
var collection = BaseDatos.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(nombreCollection);
collection.Insert(doc);
```

The code works fine but it inserts only the first BSON document of the file.
Is there a way to insert into the same collection all the Documents of the text file?

Appreciate any help you may give me.

Answer (score 1):

BsonDocument.Parse(str) parses only one JSON doc. You have more of them in the string.

Basically you have 2 options:

If you can change the format of the input file so that each JSON is on separate line (you'll need last empty line to be notified about last obj), you can use readline module:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var file = 'data.d'

var readline = require('readline')
  , rl = readline.createInterface({
        input : fs.createReadStream(file)
      , output: process.stdout
      , terminal: false
    })

    rl.on('line', function (line) {

      console.log('line: ')
      var obj = {}
      try {
        obj = JSON.parse(line)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error: ' + e)
        return
      }
      console.log(obj)
    })
```

If you can't change the format, I afraid you have to parse the string yourself, find boundaries of JSON objects and parse them individually, something like that (assuming you don't have nested JSON objects, otherwise it will be more complicated):

```
var fs = require('fs')
var file = 'data.d'
var s = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
var start = s.indexOf('{')
var end = s.indexOf('{', start + 1)
while (start !== -1 && end !== -1) {
  var oneObjStr = s.substring(start, end)
  var oneObj = JSON.parse(oneObjStr)
  // save obj into db
  console.log(oneObj)
  start = end
  end = s.indexOf('{', start + 1)
}
if (start !== -1) {
  var lastOne = JSON.parse(s.substring(start, s.length))
  // save the last obj into db
  console.log(lastOne)
}
```

I think, you can also store objects into an array and store that array in one mongodb insert:

```
var objs = []
objs.push(oneObj)
// save into db in batch
// db.coll.insert(objs, ...)
```

(just to clarify - data.d contains your input file)

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to edit the file, so after each Json document I inserted a blank line and then while imported, split it into an array and create BSON Documents for each of them.